# Cross Table Issue in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos

Calculating Growth in crosstab Cognos. I need to bring the previous year's value to the current year column. Please help me.

-322,129,132.49 should be coming the PY1 column in the Year of 2018.

[image]

Comment: If you're getting stuff in the wrong place you might want to look at the model that you used to create the report as well as examine the report, especially the report layout.

Answer (score 0):

Missing information:

- version of Cognos
- sample data
- column names
- What should PY1 be for 2017?

...but I'll try.

I think what you are saying is that the 2017 PY1 should be 0 and 2018 PY1 should be -322,129,132.49.  If that is correct...

Adjust your query to return PY1 in the correct year.  This may involve multiple queries joined together.  Here is sample SQL to consider:

```
select a.[year]
, a.unnamed_code_value
, coalesce(b.PY1, 0) as PY1
, a.en_Amount
from (
    select [year]
    , unnamed_code_value
    , sum(en_Amount) as en_Amount
    from table1
    group by [year]
    , unnamed_code_value
) a
left outer join (
    select [year] + 1 as 'year'
    , unnamed_code_value
    , sum(en_Amount) as PY1
    from table1
    group by [year] + 1
    , unnamed_code_value
) b on b.[year] = a.[year]
   and b.unnamed_code_value = a.unnamed_code_value
```